# Creating a circular symbol with an arrowhead and a partly dashed line

Tags: adobe-illustrator, symbols

I've just started to use Illustrator. Maybe someone can help me and explain how to make this symbol.

I had trouble when trying to remove the segments of the object. I tried the knife and scissors tools, but they didn't work

[image: Circular arrow]

Comment: Hi Никита Цмыг, Welcome GD.SE! Can you tell us what you have tried and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: AndrewH, I need to remove segments of the object, I tried tools knife and scissors, but does not work.

Answer (score 6):

- Make a dashed stroke in a 3/4 of an arc of a circle

[image: dashed stroke]

- Copy/paste in front: <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Mac or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> Win and uncheck the dashed stroke
- **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Add anchor points**
- Select the last bottom three points with the **Direct Selection Tool** and delete them

[image: Points]

- Using the **Polygon Tool** [image: Polygon Tool],
  click on the document to create a 3 side polygon
- Rotate it 180º, fill it black, no stroke and place it at the left
  side of the arc
- Get the **Direct Selection Tool** and round the corners using the
  **Round Corners Widget**

[image: Round corners]

- Select all and group <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> Mac or
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> Win

[image: Animation]